# Why was this world created?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, creation

As I've researched, G-d has many creations, trillions of worlds before this world, and will create many after this world.

Why did G-d create this world?

Comment: Why was the world created
Why God Created the World

Comment: Can you add a source for God creating trillions of worlds?  It would help us to answer if we had the context of what you've read already.

Comment: @MonicaCellio : thanks ! I find that in Islam Hadith. in Arabic and Persian. that your friends (here) know them OFF-TOPIC http://myenglishblog.persianblog.ir/post/2/

Comment: Well, yeah. I mean, Judaism doesn't believe in the ahadith. Basing a question in Judaism on what they say doesn't seem to me very logical. (Oh, and besides what @MonicaCellio sought, a source for trillions of worlds before this one, you should source that there'll be many worlds after this one.)

Comment: I know that Judaism doesn't believe in the ahadith but when you tell me mention of my research resource then i create a blog post for you. thanks. This is a mental issue that G-d always creates the creations.? or not?

Comment: If G-d is the Creator and created in the past, why not create in the future?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I am not sure if the claim that the many [I learned 6] worlds were before this one and then were destroyed, (a la http://www.globalyeshiva.com/profiles/blogs/why-hashem-created-so-many) or if it refers to the many extant planets out there which we know through empirical evidence exist.

Comment: The first premise is absolute not true at all, there was nothing ever created before this world, especially not "trillions" that is totally made up with no evidence and is compelte herisy, there are many "spirital worlds" but they were not "created" *before* this world in time, but in spiritual space, and still exist now... quote the sources for claims

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rabbi Tzvi Freeman has an excellent article entitled "[What is the Purpose of Existence?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/52551/jewish/What-is-the-Purpose-of-Existence.htm)" He thoroughly examines the classical answers to the question of G-d's purpose in creating the world (to reveal His abilities, to be able to practice good etc), and explains the difficulties with them, and concludes with the explanation offered by the Chassidic masters:

> As we said, G-d has no need or "reason" for creating a world. He just
>   did it. But when He did it, He did it with a purpose. He decided to
>   desire to have two opposites at once: A very mundane, real world... discovering its Creator in all its aspects.
>
> G-d doesn't need a home. He's perfectly comfy doing nothing at all. He just decided to desire this. And He can decide to desire whatever
>   He decides to desire.
>
> That doesn't mean -- and this is crucial to note -- that He doesn't
>   really desire it. On the contrary, have you ever dealt with an
>   unreasonable desire? Reason has its limits, but when things are
>   decided "just because," you are no longer dealing with anything you
>   can work around. You are dealing with the total person.
>
> So too, here. G-d decides, "This is what I choose to want, just
>   because I so decided." And so, He is there in that desire in all His
>   essence.
>
> The creation contains only the most minimal inkling of a ray of a
>   reflection of the Creator's light. We are all unnecessary nothings.
>   But in His desire for His creation and its fulfillment, there He is in
>   His entirety.

Comment: To have a desire to do something else means to be incomplete in some way and thus imperfect. Also its deeply problematic that G-d, blessed be He, has no "reason" for creating the world and He just did it arbitrarily because you then necessarily have something that in philosophy is called brute contingency and brute facts, which causes inumerable metaphysical issues, not to mention that it contradicts strong PSR which one necessarily has to affirm if they don't want to run into self-refuting idea fallacy. So this is a very strange response by the Chassidic masters and I don't think its good.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Sadia Gaon in his famous work אמונות ודעות  says god created the world because he is good and wants to "bestow good". The premise being that he need the world in order to do good. I do not like this answer as it takes away from God being omnipotent. Moreover he endes off even worse in may opinion, see below.
That being said, I haven't seen any better answer in my lifetime. I think this is one of those questions that we must leave unanswered and still believe.

this notion was used by Yaakov Shweky in a song:

> כי הטוב ידבק בטוב
>   ולכן יצווה עמו לבחור בטוב
>   והקל הטוב חפץ להיטיב

Reference:
רס"ג , אמונות ודאות, מאמר שלישי at the beginning:

> כיון שנתברר שהוא קדמון שלא היה עמו מאומה היתה אם כן יצירתו את העולם טובה מאתו וחסד, וכפי שהזכרנו בסוף המאמר הראשון בסבת בריאת כל הדברים. וממה שנמצא גם בכתובים שהוא טוב ומטיב...והגדול שבחסדיו על בריותיו הוא שנתן להם את ההויה כלומר מה שהמציא אותם אחר שלא היו, וכפי שאמר לנבחריהם 'כל הנקרא בשמי ולכבודי בראתיו'.‏

Comment: You should translate the hebrew. I doubt the questioner can read it.

Comment: G-d created trillions of worlds?